# To speed up python programming

Tags: python-3.x

I have multiple process excute at the same time and they have some endless for loop or while loop to monitor some data in the network.At the moment I am using thread to execute them and stop as per the certain codition.

In this scenario which one is better?
1.Multiprocess
2.Multi threading
3.asyncio

One thing I want to mention the process which are execute simultaneously, they are not dependent each other.

Please share  your thought

Thank you

Comment: how many connections per second? how long would a connection lasts? what would you do with the connection ? cpu bound or io bound?
these are important factors to you question and you did not post enough information

btw : if speed matters, actual benchmark stats is always better than asking in the dark

Comment: We have different types of devices like sov, motor, analog, digital, control valves etc. Each type of device has 100 items.

Now our software continuously monitors with the PLC to read some property of each type according to which we need to write some property.

As an example, if motor on command is high then we need to write on feedback at PLC end high. At the moment, I face the problem that it takes too much time to update.

Comment: Network is like that:- 1.PLC connect to OPC UA Server 2.Python Application acts as OPC Client.Update time between plc and OPC client is 100 ms.

Answer (score 0):

before going tweak your server code , do check the possibility of device-side-slow-update.

besides that, in my opinion you are in a many-short-read-few-long-write pattern
divide your reading and updating payload should be the first thing to consider
handling read and update sequentially in one thread , may suffer heavy impact when facing a burst of high number of update.

you can start by setting up two thread pool , one for read and one for update
and tweak thread pool size based on benchmark stats
if  cpu usage keeps on high (> 70%) , go asyncio

btw: update your question is better than leave your information in comments

Comment: Hello Sir, Thank you for suggestion.Yes I already divided reading and writing thread pool.I try to use Multiprocess.Maybe I put my project in github to make you better understand.I will come back to you .Thank you for your wonderfull support

Comment: you are welcomed , you can find me as bigdataolddriver on  github